# Svelte file input does not trigger reactivity if the same file path is chosen

Tags: javascript, svelte

In a Svelte component, I have a basic file input and the files attribute are binded to variable `files`. If the user input the same file path as the previous input, all reactive statements dependent on `files` will not be triggered (`console.log(files)` in this example). `on:change` and `on:input` have the same behavior.

```
<script>
let files;
$: console.log(files)
</script>

<input type="file" bind:files/>
```

Is there a way to trigger reactivity everytime when user inputs a file, even if the file path is the same as before? Because the file content may have been changed, and I would want to parse the file again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could clear the input on click:

```html
<script>
    let files = [];

    function onClick(e) {
        e.target.value = '';
        files = [];
    }
</script>

<input type="file" bind:files on:click={onClick}/>
```

On [some newer browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_filesystemhandle) you could implement a reload functionality separately by working with [file system handles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemHandle) instead.

```html
<script>
    let handles = [];
    let files = [];

    async function onOpenFiles(e) {
        handles = await window.showOpenFilePicker();
        onReload();
    }
    async function onReload() {
        files = await Promise.all(handles.map(handle => handle.getFile()));
    }
</script>

<button on:click={onOpenFiles}>Open</button>
<button on:click={onReload}>Reload</button>
```

(Only works over HTTPS, so it will not work in the REPL iframe)